When trying to access view from Azure app service getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, but works fine when run from Visual Studio
When trying to access view from Azure app service getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, but works fine when run from Visual Studio.
Using Asp.net Core 6 in Visual Studio 2022 with jQuery JavaScript Library v3.6.0
The page is accessed with -
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-controller="UserList" asp-action="UserList">User List</a>
</li>

The controller -
 public async Task<IActionResult> UserList()
 {
     List<UserListViewModel> users = await _userListControllerHelper.MapToViewModel(_context);
     return View(users);
 }

The MapToViewModel  -
public async Task<List<UserListViewModel>> MapToViewModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
     
    List<UserListViewModel> model = new List<UserListViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in context.Users)
    {
        var userDetails = new UserListViewModel();

        userDetails.Username = user.UserName ?? string.Empty;

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            userDetails.Role += role;
        }

        userDetails.Email = user.Email ?? string.Empty;

        IEnumerable<UsersHospital> usersHospitals = _usersHosptialRepository.GetHospitalIdsFromUserId(user.Id);

        userDetails.UsersHospitalId = usersHospitals is not null ? usersHospitals.FirstOrDefault().id : 0;

        userDetails.Hospital = usersHospitals is not null ? _lookupRepository.EnabledHospitals().FirstOrDefault(x => x.HospitalId == usersHospitals.FirstOrDefault().HospitalId).Hospital : string.Empty;

        userDetails.HasEmailBeenConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed;

        userDetails.IsLockedOut = user.LockoutEnabled && (user.LockoutEnd is not null && user.LockoutEnd > DateTime.Now);

        model.Add(userDetails);
      
    }

    return model.ToList();
}

view -
@model IEnumerable<UserListViewModel>
@section breadcrumb{
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">User List</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
}

@if (TempData["AlertMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-message alert-success">
        @TempData["alertMessage"]
    </div>
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-md-12 border-0">
        <div class="card-body align-content-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register New User</a>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="card-deck col-md-12 overflow-auto">
        <div class="card col-md-12 border p-0">
            <div class="card-header">
                <b>List of Active Users</b>
            </div>
            <div class="UsersList card-body align-content-center">                
                <div class="row p-1 border-1 border-bottom border-top flex-container">
                    <div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end"><b>Username</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end"><b>User Email</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-1 col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 border-1 border-end"><b>User Email Confirmed</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end"><b>User Role</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end"><b>User Location</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3"><b>Actions</b></div>
                 </div>

                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @if (!item.IsLockedOut) 
                        {
                            <div class="row p-1 border-1 border-bottom flex-container card-deck">
                                <div class="card col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 border-1 border-end">@item.Username</div>
                                <div class="card col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 border-1 border-end">@item.Email</div>
                                <div class="card col-xxl-1 col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 border-1 border-end">
                                    @item.HasEmailBeenConfirmed
                                    @if (!item.HasEmailBeenConfirmed)
                                    {
                                        <br />
                                        <a asp-controller="UserList" asp-action="ResendConfirmationEmail" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" asp-route-useremail="@item.Email" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("UserList", "UserList", new { area = "" })">
                                            Resend
                                        </a>
                                    }
                                </div>
                                <div class="card col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)</div>
                                <div class="card col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 border-1 border-end">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hospital)</div>
                                <div class ="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                                    <a asp-controller="UserList" method="get" asp-action="UserEdit" asp-route-userEmail="@item.Email" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                        Edit User
                                    </a>
                                    <button class="lockUnlockOrDeleteUser btn btn-primary btn-block" data-id="@item.Email" data-type="lock">
                                        Lock User
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="lockUnlockOrDeleteUser btn btn-danger btn-block" data-id="@item.Email" data-type="delete">
                                        Delete User
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck col-md-12 overflow-auto">
        <div class="card col-md-12 border p-0">
            <div class="card-header">
                <b>List of Locked Out Users</b>
            </div>
            <div class="UsersList card-body align-content-center">

                <div class="row p-1 border-1 border-bottom border-top flex-container">
                    <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end"><b>Username</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end"><b>User Role</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end"><b>User Email</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end"><b>User Location</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3"><b>Actions</b></div>
                </div>

                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @if (item.IsLockedOut)
                        {
                        <div class="row p-1 border-1 border-bottom flex-container">
                            <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end">@item.Username</div>
                            <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end">@item.Role</div>
                            <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end">@item.Email</div>
                            <div class="col-xxl col-xl col-lg col-md border-1 border-end">@item.Hospital</div>
                            <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                                <button class="lockUnlockOrDeleteUser btn btn-primary btn-block" data-id="@item.Email" data-type="unlock">
                                    Unlock User
                                </button>
                                <button class="lockUnlockOrDeleteUser btn btn-danger btn-block" data-id="@item.Email" data-type="delete">
                                    Delete User
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script>

    $(document).on('click', '.lockUnlockOrDeleteUser', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to " + event.target.dataset.type + " this user?: " + event.target.dataset.id)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LockUnlockOrDeleteUser", "UserList")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { userEmail: event.target.dataset.id, type: event.target.dataset.type },
            })
            .done(function (response) {
                switch (response.succeeded) {
                    case false:
                                alert("Failed to " + event.target.dataset.type + " user, please contact FNSD administration for help.");
                        break;
                    case true:
                                alert("User successfully " + event.target.dataset.type + "ed");
                                var urlToRedirect = '@Url.Action("userlist", "userlist")';
                                window.location.href = urlToRedirect;
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response) + ": Please contact FNSD administration for help.");
                }
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("AJAX request failed: " + errorThrown + ": Please contact FNSD administration for help.");
            });
        };
    });
</script>
}

I don't know why this is happennig.  Tried deleting all cookies as it says, but that doesn't solve the problem.
Any help will be gratefully received.

This is off topic, but you probably don't want to pass your db context as a parameter.

duly noted.  Thanks

Does the issue resolved? If not, may I know which request is the problematic one that keeps redirecting? Maybe we can press F12 in the browser and see the network blade for getting more information. Your codes looks good and just like what you said, it worked well in local VS but the issue only occurred in Azure. May I know whether there's an authentication mechanism inside your app?

Yes, it has been resolved.  I did f12 and looked at the Netwok blade, that helped a lot.  Thank you.

I found a couple of things. The reason I was getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS was due to the system looking for a PageNotFound view and there wasn't one. So I added one and that fixed that problem.
Loading the UserList page was giving the Status Code: 302 Found. This was a middleware problem:
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 2ff3e9926a1b6c03
TraceId: 7314731274212a962b5c1323b0299200
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 400070d4-0005-f900-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /UserAdmin/UserList
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

The problem was:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

This was solved by adding
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True

to the connection string.
